# Carthage: How to get the very latest version of a given repository?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, carthage

The Cartfile documentation makes the assertion:

> If no version requirement is given, any version of the dependency is allowed.

with the contradictory example:

```
# Use the latest version
github "jspahrsummers/xcconfigs"
```

Furthermore, it is not stated, but from testing, I infer that "latest" is actually the version of the latest tag. Is this interpretation correct? And if so, how does one specify the very latest commit - do you have to manually check and specify the latest commit, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#cartfile) states

> Carthage supports several kinds of version requirements:
>
> - >= 1.0 for “at least version 1.0”
> - ~> 1.0 for “compatible with version 1.0”
> - == 1.0 for “exactly version 1.0”
> - "some-branch-or-tag-or-commit" for a specific Git object (anything allowed by git rev-parse)

so I believe

```
github "jspahrsummers/xcconfigs" "HEAD"
```

should work as expected, since "HEAD" is a valid argument for `git rev-parse`

Alternatively

```
github "jspahrsummers/xcconfigs" "master"
```

or any other branch

Comment: Indeed it does, and is the best answer.  I'll mark this as such once the embargo lifts. - Thanks.

Comment: Adding ``github "eonist/swift-utils" "39c35f4"`` to a Cartfile worked for me. ``39c35f4`` would be the id of the latest commit

Comment: And can you use github "eonist/swift-utils" "develop" "39c35f4"? Hi @Eonist :) edit: actually you can do it without specifying the branch, it find it itself

Comment: Is it possible to have versioning if Cartfile aims the branch other than `master`? If yes, how is this achieved in Cartfile itself and what does repo need to support in order to make it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Simply `github "jakecraige/RGB"` will yell `No tagged versions found for github "jakecraige/RGB"`

Better is to use `github "jakecraige/RGB" "master"`

You may want to read [Carthage Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/109330/carthage-tutorial-getting-started)

> branch name / tag name / commit name means “Use this specific git branch / tag / commit”. For example, you could specify master, or a commit has like 5c8a74a.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by mdiep on Carthage's github page:

> The latest version refers to something that has an actual version—a release or tag. If you want the most latest commit, you need to specify the branch you want to pin to.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the version number out. Mine looks like this and it works:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire"
github "auth0/JWTDecode.swift"
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The [docs](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md) say "If no version requirement is given, any version of the dependency is allowed"

Comment: this is acceptable, **if** the framework provider has tagged releases in the repository, which adhere to the semantic version spec.

Comment: No, this is not acceptable. He asks for the latest version, not the latest release. If you are developing the framework, making a release for every commit is crazy.