# How to build a Carthage framework from git branch

Tags: git, alamofire, carthage

Alamofire has a [bug](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/1951) that is fixed in a future release. The author has already fixed the bug and the solution is merged in the master branch. Is there any way for me to use carthage so I can create a framework file that includes this fix? Currently when I use carthage against AF [repo](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git) it clones release v4.4 which still has the bug.

I would also be open to a solution, where in I can checkout the latest code from AF repo on my local machine and use carthage to create a framework locally. I just want the SessionDelegate.swift file to contain the [latest](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/1951/files#diff-3ea027b9dd0159892c4f202d768a93fe) code so I can move forward with my testing.

Answer (score 23):

In short, the branch can be referenced by name by using the following in your Cartfile:

`github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "branch-name"`

For a little bit more in-depth explanation of what this can accomplish, consult the [documentation](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#cartfile):

> Carthage supports several kinds of version requirements:
>
> - >= 1.0 for “at least version 1.0”
> - ~> 1.0 for “compatible with version 1.0”
> - == 1.0 for “exactly version 1.0”
> - "some-branch-or-tag-or-commit" for a specific Git object (anything allowed by git rev-parse)

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459998/5423311), but felt the question was not a duplicate, despite the fact that the answer is.